# Initializing array in ng-init from external file

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">    
<head>
    <script src="js_libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="somenames.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-init="names">
    <ul ng-repeat="name in names">
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**somenames.js** is very simple.

```
        var names = ['Andrew', 'Ben', 'Chad'];
```

When I open the html in the browser lists no name. I do not want to use controller. I just want to initialize from file. 
How can I do this thing i.e. initilizing from an external file ?

I wrote a controller, but the result is negative. The syntaxe s OK, the logic is OK (I guess) but nothing shows in the browser.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="">   
<head>
    <script src="js_libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>                        
    <div class="container" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="name in names">
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <script>
    function namesCtrl($scope){
         $scope.names = ['Andrew', 'Ben', 'Chad'];
    }
</script>
</body>
```

It the same situation as before. How to correct the file ?

Comment: I think you can't. You must use a controller for initialize names in your scope

Comment: You have to define a controller in order to make angular work on your page.

Comment: You will have to write *something* anyway to make ngInit use global values. Quite a few ways, though to achieve this.

Comment: Yes. You are all right. I'll use a controller. Thanks. I thought I can use this way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't initialize values without the use of a controller :S,

Talking about your file, you can add a value in the "ng-app" property to define a container in this case "app".

In the controller you can create a module that refers to that container in this case "mainApp", in that way you will be able to attach controllers to it as the format:
       `"name_of_your_variable".controller("name_of_Controller", function($scope){
 //body controller });`

Finally inside the controller you can add the attributes you need, in this case your array of names, then you will be able to access to the value with the expressions. Check the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="app">   
<head>
    <script src="js_libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
        Array:  {{names}}
        <ul ng-repeat="name in names">
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
     <script>
    var mainApp = angular.module("app", []);
    mainApp.controller("namesCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.names = ['Andrew', 'Ben', 'Chad']
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Hope this can help you :)